# How does Set work with Get in Singly Linked List in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm a newbie in JavaScript and trying to learn Data Structures and Algorithms.

I'm struggling at understanding how `set` works by depending on `getIndex`.

Here's the code:

```
class Node{
  constructor(val){
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null
  }
}

class SinglyLinkedList{
  constructor(){
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.length = 0;
  }
  push(val){
    let newNode = new Node(val);
    if(!this.head){
      this.head = newNode
      this.tail = this.head
    }else{
      this.tail.next = newNode;
      this.tail = newNode
    }
    this.length++;
    return this;
  }
  getIndex(index){
    if(index > this.length || index < 0) return null;
    let counter = 0, current = this.head;
    while(counter !== index){
      current = current.next;
      counter++;
    }
    return current; // Here we return a value of the node we found
  }
  set(val, index){
    let foundNode = this.getIndex(index);
    if(foundNode){
      foundNode.val = val; 
      // We can change the value of the node we founded in getIndex. Then the set works
      // I don't understand why we can do this. 
      // Since what we do in getIndex is just returning a value of the node. 
      // How does changing that returned node can change the context of the list in term of the purpose of set
      return true;
    }
    return false;

  }
}

let list = new SinglyLinkedList();
list.push(88);
list.push(33);
list.push(11)

list.getIndex(1) // Output: Node: {val: 33, next: 11}. Why does changing this returned node can change the context of the whole list?
list.set(77,1)   // Output: true. List (new) : 88 -> 77 -> 11
```

Basically, what I'm concerning is at the `getIndex` method, we return a `current` node. Then we change it in the `set` method. But does `getIndex` just return a value of that node ? So why can we change the whole list when changing that returned node from `getIndex` (in `set`) ?

Sorry for my silly question. Feel free to adjust my knowledge, expecially the `class` aspect. Please help! Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is a little confusing with all the `get` and `set`. Could you reword it? Also, this guide might help clear up a little confusion: https://humanwhocodes.com/blog/2019/01/computer-science-in-javascript-linked-list/

Comment: Thanks for the article @PLZHELP. My question is generally : at the ```getIndex``` method, what we return is a node. So when I change that returned node in ```set```, why can it also change the list? Because at ```getIndex``` we just return a value of the node. Sorry for my lack of knowledge of class methods

Comment: @PLZHELP I edited the question for more clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are not returning the value, you are returning a reference to the value. The whole concept of a singly-linked-list is based on references.

As an experiment, try to return a new node instead.

```
return new Node(current.val)
```

It will not perform the same. This concept at a deeper level is called a `pointer`.

Comment: Ahh Ok. I get it now. Thank you very much @PLZHELP